# Proving composite function properties

Tags: calculus, functions, functional-equations

A continuous function $f: [-1, 1] \to R$ satisfies that

$$
  f(2x^2 - 1) = 2xf(x)
$$

Furthermore, another function defined $g: G \to R$ with $G = \{t \in R: t \ne nπ, n \in Z\}$ as

$$
  g(t) = \dfrac{f(\cos{t})}{\sin{t}}
$$

With these two functions provided, I would like to know

1. f(-1) and f(1)
2. Show that function $g$ is an odd function
3. For every $t \in G$, show that $g(t) = g(t/2)$

I am trying to figure out what is the main point of such a question, and as far as I know about functions, I tried the first and second ones as follows

1.
$$
    \begin{align*}
        & 2x^2 -1 = -1, \quad x = 0 \\\
        & f(-1) = 2 \cdot 0 \cdot f(-1) = 0
    \end{align*}
$$

$$
    \begin{align*}
        & 2x^2 -1 = 1, \quad x = \pm1 \\\
        & f(1) = 2 \cdot f(1) = -2 \cdot f(1), \quad f(1) = 0
    \end{align*}
$$

2.
$$
    \begin{align*}
        & g(-t) = \dfrac{f(\cos(-t))}{\sin(-t)} = -\dfrac{f(\cos(t))}{\sin(t)} \\
        & 2x^2 - 1 = \cos{x} (?)
    \end{align*}
$$

Actually, I think I do not fully understand this question, and I think what I did is probably nonsense. What I want to know is how can I solve them, and what concepts are these questions asking, it looks like this is a composite function, yet I am not sure where to start or to delve into related concepts.

Comment: What you did so far is correct (except whatever you intended with $2x^2-1 = \cos x$). In fact, in 2. you can conclude that $g(-t) = -g(t)$ and hence $g$ is odd. The third question is similar.

Comment: Thanks! I was wondering if my thought is naive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the advice from Klaus, the answers for 1. and 2. are already described in the OP.

As for the last question, it can be derived from

$$
    \begin{align*}
        g(t/2) & = \dfrac{f(\cos(t/2))}{\sin(t/2)} = \dfrac{f(2\cos^2(t/2) - 1)}{2\sin(t/2)\cos(t/2)} = \dfrac{f(\cos{t})}{\sin{t}}
    \end{align*}
$$